# iOS game development confused

Tags: ios, game-engine

I've decided to start developing Iphone games. I am however a bit lost on the whole thing.

What i wan't is to find a good book, that i can follow. The problem though is that all the books I've found that had good reviews were outdated by now (I guess), so i started trying to find some tutorials on the subject. This confused me even more!

At the moment I've got an basic understanding of Xcode and objective-c and I'd like to keep on writing the code for my games. The tutorials however did almost always use some kind of game engine that spared the user from most of the coding.

My question now is: Should i use a game engine that do most of the coding and speed up the process? And can you recommend any good books on game development for IOS that isn't outdated?

Comment: Look at Apple docs and Sprite Kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a specific answer someone can give you on whether you should use a game engine or not. It depends on the game you're wanting to make first off. For example, if you're wanting to make 2D games, you can always just a game engine, or you can find a way to make it by yourself (mostly just for a learning experience), and if you're wanting to make 3d games, you can always just use OpenGL or something similar to that.

Basically, nobody can tell if you should use an engine, you have to test and trial/error different ways that would seem efficient and fun to you.

2D game engine
[Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download/)

3D game engine - by apple
[OpenGL ES 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Here is a website that you can preorder books for learning iOS 7 programming, and iOS 7 related game tutorials, so check this out

[ios 7 tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/47868/two-new-ios-7-books)

Hope this helps you out!